# batch file to move all files of a type to a different drive maintaining the original directory tree

Tags: batch-file, archiving

The closest thing I have seen here uses a command "mv" which apparently is not a Windows command.  Windows "Move" command won't do the job.

I have a text file which lists every one of the files that needs to be moved showing its full path from c:\ (example  C:\di1\dir2\dir3\dir4\filetomove.png.
Some of the sub-directory names have spaces in them and there is no standard order.  Some may be one level deep with others 5 levels deep.

I would like to do this such that I end up with a new list that is exactly the same as the old except that the drive letter would be X:\  instead of C:\

There are many other files in these same directories and they should not be touched.  Only those in the list I am working with.

Comment: Have you tried robocopy? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc733145.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, *Robocopy* is more flexible and less error prone, but here's some  batch "code" that reads the text file and for each line (assuming that the full path of every file to be moved is on a line):

- "calculates" the destination folder (actually replaces the 1st character of the file's parent folder - that should be the drive letter - with the one stored in `DESTINATION_DRIVE`)
- tests if the new parent dir exists, and if not it creates it (and all intermediary dirs) - this is why the `move` command used to fail: because the destination parent dir didn't exist. A note here: if a file with the same name as the destination dir exists, the move operation will obviously fail
- performs the move operation

The script:

```
@echo off
set DESTINATION_DRIVE=e

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (files.txt) do (
    call :move_file "%%f"
)
goto :eof

:move_file
    set _SRC_DIR=%~dp1
    set _DST_DIR=%DESTINATION_DRIVE%%_SRC_DIR:~1%
    if not exist "%_DST_DIR%\nul" (
        mkdir "%_DST_DIR%"
    )
    move %1 "%_DST_DIR%" 
    goto :eof
```

As a flaw, after moving the files, the script might leave empty dirs on the source drive.